# On Simple Algebraic Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups

I was skimming a paper and got stuck in the middle. As you see in the underlined parts, the authors first assumed that $\mathcal{G}$ is a simple algebraic group. Then $\mathcal{G}$ is defined to be $SL_n(\mathbb{F})$.
[image]

But according to the descriptions of [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123009/simply-connected-simple-algebraic-groups), $SL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is almost-simple but not simple algebraic group. I'm not so familiar with theory of algebraic groups and got so confused. How should I explain this? I would be grateful for any guide.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the author isn't claiming that $SL_n$ is a simple algebraic group, just reusing the same notation.

Comment: I don't think so. Because there is a lemma in the paper, namely Lemma 2.5, which is about simple algebraic groups and it frequently used for $\mathcal{G}=SL_n(F)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A algebraic group over a field k is simple if it is non-commutative and has no closed connected normal subgroups other than itself and e. The word "almost simple" is used if we wish to emphasize that the group need not be simple as an abstract group).(see, J. E. Humphreys, Linear algebraic group (1998), pp168).

Comment: Since $SL_n/Z(SL_N) \cong PSL_N$ is simple, all the normal subgroups of $SL_n$ have to be contained in $Z(SL_n)$ which is not connected. Can we deduce from this argument that $SL_n$ does not contain any nontrivial connected normal subgroup and hence it is simple algebraic group (according the above definition)?